# How to store int into hash table using division method and quadratic probing to avoid collision in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable

So recently I had a quiz for my Data Structure subject, and there was a question involving hash tables. My lecturer did teach the theories behind it but never taught the way to code it which was extremely frustrating. I tried to google any info on how to do it, but to no avail. Now after the quiz, I just want to know how this is done so I can improve my knowledge for further tests or quizzes. I've also added my submission incase anyone needed to see it.

[image: My Data Structure Quiz]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int hash[30]; 
string key;
int value, keylength;
char yesorno;

int division(int keylength){
for(int i = 0; i <= keylength; i++){
    value = keylength % 30;
    hash[value];
    cout << "The bucket/cell location : " << hash[value] << endl;
}
}


/*int hashing(int hash[], int value){
for(int k = 0; k <=30; k++){
    hash[k] = value;
    cout << "The bucket/cell location : " << hash[value] << endl;
}
}*/

int main(){

do {
cout << "Enter planet name : ";
cin >> key;
keylength == key.length();
division(keylength);
//hashing(hash, value);
cout << "Do you want to continue...? " << endl;
cout << "Press 'Y' or 'y' for Yes else 'N' or 'n' : ";
cin >> yesorno;
} while(yesorno = 'Y' || 'y');

return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is your best attempt of quadratic probing part? The example in wikipedia is pretty good https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi Honestly, this is the first few times I've done quadratic probing programming. I can do quadratic probing no problem by writing it down one by one. But not programming it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing this link provide a numerical example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not asking for storing `int` into hash table but the value of position in hash table where `key` (here planet names) is stored. Quadratic probing will be implemented somewhat like this:

1. Create hash value from key using division method
2. If `hashtable[value]` is unoccupied then no need of any probing. We occupy it and return value. Else we will start quadratic probing like this:

   `for(int i=0;i<30;i++){ probe_value=(i*i+value)%30; // quadratic probing if(hashtable[probe_value] == "0"){ return probe_value; } } return -1; // as hashtabletable is full;`

Complete program code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
string hashtable[30];
int hashtableing(string key){
        int value,probe_value;
        value= (key.length())%30; //division
        if(hashtable[value] == "0" || hashtable[value] ==key){
                hashtable[value]=key;
                return value;
        }else{
                for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
                        probe_value=(i*i+value)%30; // quadratic probing
                        if(hashtable[probe_value] == "0"){
                                return probe_value;
                        }
                }
                return -1; // as hashtabletable is full;
        }
}


int main(){
        string key;
        char choice='Y';
        for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
                hashtable[i]="0"; //0 indicates cell is unoccupied for probing
        }
        while(choice != 'N' && choice !='n'){
                cout<<"Enter planet name:"<<endl;
                cin>>key;
                cout<<"The bucket/cell location :"<< hashtableing(key)<<endl;
                cout<<"Do you want to continue...?"<<endl;
                cout<<"Press 'Y' or 'y' for Yes else 'n' or 'N':";
                cin>>choice;
        }
        return 0;
}
```